# What conclusions can be drawn from the 'feature importance' attribute of a Random Forrest?

Tags: random-forest, inference, scikit-learn

I am working on my class project for machine learning, for a smaller part of my project I am fitting a [`sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor) to my data over a range of `n_estimators` and `max_features` and plotting the resulting out of box error versus `n_estimators` for each value of `max_features`. I noticed that `RandomForestRegressor` has an attribute `feature_importances_` that I would like to try to draw some conclusions from.

The data I am fitting has 6 features and 1 response variable. I know based on how this data is created (data from a real physical process) that a specific feature is the "most important" to the response's value. Though when I inspect the attribute `feature_importances_` this variable is always of very low importance.

**What can be said about this discrepancy?**

After thinking about it I have to assume that this is explained by the fact that a Random Forest "does not care or know" about where the data comes from. The importance it places on the features is purely based on their predictive power; their power to lower the error rate for a given tree, for a given split. **Does this mean nothing about the process that generates this data can be inferred?**

**In general, and to make the answer(s) hopefully more succinct and useful to others too, what are the top few conclusions that can be drawn from the attribute `feature_importances_`? Specifically with discrepancies like the one I have outlined?**

Comment: Its best to ignore the name "feature_importnaces".  It really just measures how much your model "used" each of the features.  As you suspect, it doesn't measure anything about the universe, just about the fit model itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned already, the importance of the variable is really based on the impurity of the node. So, how purely a node separates the sample aka Gini index. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810339/how-are-feature-importances-in-randomforestclassifier-determined/15821880#15821880) for importance calculation in scikit-learn.

It can be that the first split is not done according to the most important feature as defined by a tree. So, what could happen is that your "specific feature" does the first split because that would result in better prediction.

You could have a look where your specific feature appear in the tree and also have a look how many samples get assigned to the left and right node.